# Is there a difference between "It's No Longer Needed" flag between main and per meta sites?

Tags: support, comments, meta, comment-flags

Is there a difference between usage of "It's No Longer Needed" (INLN or NLN) comment flag on main site and per meta site?

There are four kinds of comment flags.

> - It contains harassment, bigotry, or abuse.
>
>   The comment attacks a person or group.
> - It's unfriendly or unkind.
>
>   The comment is rude or condescending.
> - It's no longer needed.
>
>   This comment is outdated, conversational or not relevant to the post.
> - Something else.
>
>   A problem not listed above. Try to be as specific as possible.

Among all these, the other three will be obviously same everywhere. No kind of unkind or rude language is tolerated on both main and meta sites. My clarification is about the third flag.  Comment discussions on main and meta are different. While 15 comments are rare on main sites, it's quite common on meta where users get to clarify or give opinion on meta. Meta is meant for discussions talking place. While these discussion happen on meta, we sometimes sidetracked (perhaps by link addition or mention by other user) and talk about previous discussions which happened on meta. The discussion goes on.

A brief discussion under "It's No Longer Needed" is as follows (emphasis mine):

> This comment is outdated, **conversational or not relevant to the post**.

If a conversation between users on different post (not related to specific question) or discussion of a different post is taking place under a question or answer, we can flag them as INLN.But is it okay to flag such comments on meta sites also?

Is there a distinction between the usage of this flag between main and meta sites? Or can it be used as usual?

Comment: "Help, my house is on fire!" (Barring this parenthetical information, this comment would be appropriately marked as no longer needed, even here on meta.)

Comment: Whoa @Jason, did the house burn down in 39 minutes? Next time, order pizza. || Meta sites are pretty relaxed when it comes to moderating comments, because meta is by definition a place to discuss things. Unless a heated meta discussion is leading to insults or people are being outright rude, moderators don't usually act on comment flags on meta. So I'm not sure flagging something because it's obsolete or conversational will achieve anything on meta.

Comment: @Marshmallow Not about outdated, I'm asking about conversation (between users) and not relevant to post (I put that in bold in my question). If I'm asking about this question, some user link my previous question about flagging and gives feedback about that post. That conversation goes on.

Answer (score 4):

You're right, the very nature of meta has caused a situation where comments are used for extended discussions. Is that a problem? Usually not; people come here and *expect* discussions in comments. If there are too many of them, the 'Show x more comments ...' link will appear, so casual readers can focus on the question and answers.

The most important downside of hiding long comment threads is that a later comment which *is* 100% relevant and to the point (in the sense that it helps improving the post) might get 'buried'. Upvoting said comment might help to make it visible 'above the cut' (if the 'discussion' isn't voted on, that is) but this is definitely the point where, as a moderator, I'd consider pruning the discussion.

> If a conversation between users on different post (not related to specific question) or discussion of a different post is taking place under a question or answer, we can flag them as INLN. But is it okay to flag such comments on meta sites also?

If it's a discussion about an unrelated topic, I would ask the *commenters* to move their discussion elsewhere (preferably the "different post" you mentioned, or a dedicated chatroom) and delete their comments themselves; if the comments are deleted by flags and/or ♦ deletions the commenters will be confused and just might carry on with their discussion under the same post.

So, yes, the No Longer Needed flag is less often applicable on meta sites than it is on main sites, but you'd need to judge on a case-by-case basis whether a flag is warranted. Often, it's better to raise a custom moderator flag to explain *why* you want a group of comments to be removed.